# Insert tab doesn't work in MS Excel 2011 for Mac OS, Excel quits saying there was an error

Tags: microsoft-excel, osx-el-capitan

I am on Mac 10.11.6 El Capitan
Excel version 14.7.2

I will be grateful for your help. I am truly concerned - I can't use the Insert tab in Excel for Mac; if I try to insert anything in any file - symbol, picture, etc - Excel crashes, opens an Error reporting window (see attached).

Here is what I get from the information part of that error window:

Blame Module Name: MicrosoftComponentPlugin
Blame Module Version: 14.7.2.170228
Blame Module Offset: 0x00149510

How can I solve this? Please, advice me.
[image]

EDIT: Updated Excel to the 14.7.4 version. Still the same problem.

```
Microsoft Error Reporting log version: 
2.0 Error Signature: 
Exception: EXC_CRASH (SIGTRAP) 
Date/Time: 2017-06-02 08:50:14 +0000 
Application Name: Microsoft Excel Application 
Bundle ID: com.microsoft.Excel 
Application Signature: XCEL 
Application Version: 14.7.4.170508 Crashed Module 
Name: merp Crashed Module Version: 2.2.4.170508 
Crashed Module Offset: 0x00004422 
Blame Module Name: MicrosoftComponentPlugin 
Blame Module Version: 14.7.4.170508 
Blame Module Offset: 0x00149510 
Application LCID: 1033
```

Thank you very much!

Comment: First thing I'd do is get it up to date & test again 14.7.4 is latest.

Comment: @Tetsujin Well, MS didn't suggest to do that yet. I get automatic notification on updates, none has been shown yet. Edit: I have just found this update. Installing now. Let's see if it fixes the issue. I'll be back. Thank you.

Comment: very much out of left field.. a test. What view-type do you have in the open/save dialogs? Icon & coverflow have been known to crash certain apps, column & list are fine [I have no idea if Office is affected, but it's worth a try]

Comment: @Tetsujin I deleted my previous reply because it looked messy; edited the original post. As to your last comment above, sorry, but I don't understand what you mean. I wonder if there might be an issue with some Plugin as I see a line saying Blame Module Name: `MicrosoftComponentPlugin 
Blame Module Version: 14.7.4.170508` , but I have no idea what it means.

Comment: Any Finder window has 4 view types. Pick any window & try Cmd/1 then Cmd/2..3..4 to see icon, list, column & coverflow. The same is possible from any file-picker sheet [open or save dialog].

Comment: I also found this - https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/247753/excel-merp-crash

Comment: Thank you. All those examples refer to Blame Module Name: MicrosoftSetupUI; and I have a different one: Blame Module Name: MicrosoftComponentPlugin